# How can I draw loop diagrams for free field theory (physics)

Tags: diagrams

[image: loop diagram]

I have to draw the figures shown in the picture. These are loop diagrams within equation.

Comment: Why exactly do you all want to close this question as too broad just two hours after it has been asked, without even asking the OP to clarify? In fact, this question is quite specific with a few extra informations. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/189185 or http://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys851/Luty/notes/diagrams.pdf .

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a collection of diagrams for free field theory, provided as `phinman.sty` (code at the end of this answer). For spacing reasons there are two versions of each command, one with labels and one without.

[image]

The code for the demo above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{phinman} % pronounce like Feynman
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lc@{\quad}lc}
\verb"\PM{-}"    & \PM{-}    & \verb"\PMl{-}{x}{y}"          & \PMl{-}{x}{y}          \\
\verb"\PM{x}"    & \PM{x}    & \verb"\PMl{x}{x}"             & \PMl{x}{x}             \\
\verb"\PM{||}"   & \PM{||}   & \verb"\PMl{||}{u}{v}{x}{y}"   & \PMl{||}{u}{v}{x}{y}   \\
\verb"\PM{=}"    & \PM{=}    & \verb"\PMl{=}{u}{v}{x}{y}"    & \PMl{=}{u}{v}{x}{y}    \\
\verb"\PM{X}"    & \PM{X}    & \verb"\PMl{X}{u}{v}{x}{y}"    & \PMl{X}{u}{v}{x}{y}    \\
\verb"\PM{--}"   & \PM{--}   & \verb"\PMl{--}{x}{y}"         & \PMl{--}{x}{y}         \\
\verb"\PM{-o-}"  & \PM{-o-}  & \verb"\PMl{-o-}{x}{y}{z}"     & \PMl{-o-}{x}{y}{z}     \\
\verb"\PM{8}"    & \PM{8}    & \verb"\PMl{8}{x}"             & \PMl{8}{x}             \\
\verb"\PM{88}"   & \PM{88}   & \verb"\PMl{88}{x}{y}"         & \PMl{88}{x}{y}         \\
\verb"\PM{ooo}"  & \PM{ooo}  & \verb"\PMl{ooo}{x}{y}"        & \PMl{ooo}{x}{y}        \\
\verb"\PM{-8-}"  & \PM{-8-}  & \verb"\PMl{-8-}{x}{y}{z}"     & \PMl{-8-}{x}{y}{z}     \\
\verb"\PM{-88-}" & \PM{-88-} & \verb"\PMl{-88-}{x}{u}{v}{y}" & \PMl{-88-}{x}{u}{v}{y} \\
\verb"\PM{-ooo-}"& \PM{-ooo-}& \verb"\PMl{-ooo-}{x}{u}{v}{y}"& \PMl{-ooo-}{x}{u}{v}{y}\\
\verb"\PM{-o8-}" & \PM{-o8-} & \verb"\PMl{-o8-}{x}{u}{v}{y}" & \PMl{-o8-}{x}{u}{v}{y}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\clearpage
\lipsum[1]
\begin{align*}
  \PMl{-}{x}{y}         & = i\Delta(x,y)\\
  \PMl{x}{y}            & = -i\lambda\\
  \langle\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\phi(x_3)\phi(x_4)\rangle_0
                        &= \PMl{||}{x_1}{x_2}{x_3}{x_4} + \PMl{=}{x_1}{x_2}{x_3}{x_4}
                           + \PMl{X}{x_1}{x_2}{x_3}{x_4}\\
  \PMl{-o-}{x_1}{x_2}{y}&=\frac{-i\lambda}2\int\cdots\\
  \PMl{-8-}{x_1}{y}{x_2}&=\frac{-i\lambda}6i\Delta(x_1,x_2)\int\cdots\\
  \PMl{8}{y}            &=\frac{-i\lambda}6\int\cdots\\
  \text{denominator}    &=1+\PM{8}+\PM{88}+\PM{ooo}+\cdots\\
  \text{numerator}      &=\PM{--}+\PM{-8-}+\PM{-88-}+\PM{-ooo-}+\cdots\\
                        &\quad+\PM{-o-}+\PM{-o8-}+\cdots
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

---

The code for the package `phinman.sty` (pronounce like Feynman):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{phinman}[2017/04/14 Diagrams for the free field theory]
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\newcommand\PMset{\pgfqkeys{/PM}}
\newcommand\PMldef[1]{\expandafter\def\csname PMl:#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\PMl[1]{\csname PMl:#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\PMdef[1]{\expandafter\def\csname PM:#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\PM[1]{\csname PM:#1\endcsname}
\newlength\PMu
\PMu=2ex

\PMset
  {dot/.style={circle,fill,draw,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=2.5pt},
   line/.style={line width=0.6pt},
   ghostline/.style={line width=2pt,color=white}
  }

\newcommand\PMdot{node[/PM/dot]{}}
\newcommand\PMdotx[1]{node[/PM/dot,label={#1}]{}}
\newcommand\PMdota[1]{\PMdotx{[yshift=-0.5ex]above:{$#1$}}}
\newcommand\PMdotb[1]{\PMdotx{[yshift=0.5ex]below:{$#1$}}}
\newcommand\PMdotl[1]{\PMdotx{[xshift=0.5ex]left:{$#1$}}}
\newcommand\PMdotr[1]{\PMdotx{[xshift=-0.5ex]right:{$#1$}}}

\PMdef{-}%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,0) \PMdot -- (2\PMu,0)\PMdot;%
  }

\PMldef{-}#1#2%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,0) \PMdotb{#1} -- (2\PMu,0)\PMdotb{#2};%
  }

\PMdef{--}%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,0) \PMdot -- (4\PMu,0)\PMdot;%
  }

\PMldef{--}#1#2%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,0) \PMdotb{#1} -- (4\PMu,0)\PMdotb{#2};%
  }

\PMdef{x}%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,0) \PMdot
   (\PMu,\PMu) -- (-\PMu,-\PMu)
   (\PMu,-\PMu) -- (-\PMu,\PMu);%
  }

\PMldef{x}#1%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,0) \PMdotx{below:{$#1$}}
   (\PMu,\PMu) -- (-\PMu,-\PMu)
   (\PMu,-\PMu) -- (-\PMu,\PMu);%
  }

\PMdef{||}%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,\PMu) \PMdot -- (0,-\PMu) \PMdot
   (2\PMu,\PMu) \PMdot -- (2\PMu,-\PMu)\PMdot;%
  }

\PMldef{||}#1#2#3#4%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,\PMu) \PMdotl{#3} -- (0,-\PMu) \PMdotl{#4}
   (2\PMu,\PMu) \PMdotr{#1} -- (2\PMu,-\PMu)\PMdotr{#2};%
  }

\PMdef{=}%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,\PMu) \PMdot -- (2\PMu,\PMu) \PMdot
   (0,-\PMu) \PMdot -- (2\PMu,-\PMu)\PMdot;%
  }

\PMldef{=}#1#2#3#4%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,\PMu) \PMdotl{#3} -- (2\PMu,\PMu) \PMdotr{#1}
   (0,-\PMu) \PMdotl{#4} -- (2\PMu,-\PMu)\PMdotr{#2};%
  }

\PMdef{X}%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]%
    {\draw[/PM/line] (0,\PMu) \PMdot -- (2\PMu,-\PMu)\PMdot;
     \draw[/PM/ghostline] (0,-\PMu)-- (2\PMu,\PMu);
     \draw[/PM/line](0,-\PMu)\PMdot -- (2\PMu,\PMu) \PMdot;
    }%
  }

\PMldef{X}#1#2#3#4%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]%
    {\draw[/PM/line] (0,\PMu) \PMdotl{#3} -- (2\PMu,-\PMu)\PMdotr{#2};
     \draw[/PM/ghostline] (0,-\PMu)-- (2\PMu,\PMu);
     \draw[/PM/line](0,-\PMu)\PMdotl{#4}-- (2\PMu,\PMu) \PMdotr{#1};
    }%
  }

\PMdef{-o-}%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,0) \PMdot -- ++(2\PMu,0)\PMdot
   arc(-90:270:0.6\PMu) -- ++(2\PMu,0)\PMdot;%
  }

\PMldef{-o-}#1#2#3%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,0) \PMdotb{#1} -- ++(2\PMu,0)\PMdotb{#2}
   arc(-90:270:0.6\PMu) -- ++(2\PMu,0)\PMdotb{#3};%
  }

\PMdef{-8-}%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,0) \PMdot -- ++(4\PMu,0)\PMdot
   (2\PMu,0.8\PMu)\PMdot arc (0:360:0.6\PMu)
   arc (180:540:0.6\PMu);%
  }

\PMldef{-8-}#1#2#3%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,0) \PMdotb{#1} -- ++(4\PMu,0)\PMdotb{#3}
   (2\PMu,0.8\PMu)\PMdotx{above:{$#2$}} arc (0:360:0.6\PMu)
   arc (180:540:0.6\PMu);%
  }


\PMdef{-ooo-}%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,0) \PMdot -- ++(4\PMu,0)\PMdot
   (1.3\PMu,0.8\PMu)\PMdot arc (0:360:0.6\PMu)
   arc (180:360:0.6\PMu) \PMdot
   arc (180:540:0.6\PMu) arc (0:180:0.6\PMu);%
  }

\PMldef{-ooo-}#1#2#3#4%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,0) \PMdotb{#1} -- ++(4\PMu,0)\PMdotb{#4}
   (1.3\PMu,0.8\PMu)\PMdotx{above:{$#2$}} arc (0:360:0.6\PMu)
   arc (180:360:0.6\PMu) \PMdotx{above:{$#3$}}
   arc (180:540:0.6\PMu) arc (0:180:0.6\PMu);%
  }

\PMdef{8}%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,0) \PMdot arc (0:360:0.6\PMu)
   arc (180:540:0.6\PMu);%
  }

\PMldef{8}#1%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,0) \PMdotx{below:{$#1$}} arc (0:360:0.6\PMu)
   arc (180:540:0.6\PMu);%
  }

\PMdef{88}%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,-0.7\PMu) \PMdot arc (0:360:0.6\PMu) arc (180:540:0.6\PMu)
   (0,0.7\PMu) \PMdot arc (0:360:0.6\PMu) arc (180:540:0.6\PMu);%
  }

\PMldef{88}#1#2%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,-0.7\PMu) \PMdotx{below:{$#2$}} arc (0:360:0.6\PMu) arc (180:540:0.6\PMu)
   (0,0.7\PMu) \PMdotx{above:{$#1$}} arc (0:360:0.6\PMu) arc (180:540:0.6\PMu);%
  }

\PMdef{ooo}%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,0) \PMdot arc (0:360:0.6\PMu)
   arc (180:360:0.6\PMu) \PMdot
   arc (180:540:0.6\PMu) arc (0:180:0.6\PMu);%
  }

\PMldef{ooo}#1#2%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,0) \PMdotx{below:{$#1$}} arc (0:360:0.6\PMu)
   arc (180:360:0.6\PMu) \PMdotx{below:{$#2$}}
   arc (180:540:0.6\PMu) arc (0:180:0.6\PMu);%
  }

\PMdef{-88-}%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,-0.8\PMu) \PMdot arc (0:360:0.6\PMu) arc (180:540:0.6\PMu)
   (-2\PMu,0) \PMdot -- (2\PMu,0)\PMdot
   (0,0.8\PMu) \PMdot arc (0:360:0.6\PMu) arc (180:540:0.6\PMu);%
  }

\PMldef{-88-}#1#2#3#4%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,-0.8\PMu) \PMdotx{below:{$#3$}} arc (0:360:0.6\PMu) arc (180:540:0.6\PMu)
   (-2\PMu,0) \PMdotb{#1} -- (2\PMu,0)\PMdotb{#4}
   (0,0.8\PMu) \PMdotx{above:{$#2$}} arc (0:360:0.6\PMu) arc (180:540:0.6\PMu);%
  }


\PMdef{-o8-}%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,-0.8\PMu) \PMdot arc (0:360:0.6\PMu) arc (180:540:0.6\PMu)
   (-2\PMu,0) \PMdot -- (0,0) \PMdot
   arc (-90:270:0.6\PMu) -- (2\PMu,0)\PMdot;%
  }

\PMldef{-o8-}#1#2#3#4%
  {\tikz[baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}]\draw[/PM/line]
   (0,-1.5\PMu) \PMdotx{below:{$#3$}} arc (0:360:0.6\PMu) arc (180:540:0.6\PMu)
   (-2\PMu,0) \PMdotb{#1} -- (0,0) \PMdotb{#2}
   arc (-90:270:0.6\PMu) -- (2\PMu,0)\PMdotb{#4};%
  }


\endinput
```

Answer (score 5):

You can draw it with Tikz. Below I have made a couple of commands for the symbols in your drawing (you can probably find better names for them). I had to adjust the height `2pt` manually to get the lines aligned with the `+` signs. The `lipsum`s are just to see the vertical spacing. You can adjust the length of the lines and the size of the circles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\newcommand\SajadLineLength{15mm}
\newcommand\SajadCircleRadii{3mm}
\newcommand\SajadLine[2]{\tikz[baseline=-2pt]{%
    \draw[*-*](0,0) -- (\SajadLineLength,0)node[pos=0,below]{$#1$}node[pos=1,below]{$#2$};
  }}
\newcommand\SajadLineCircleMid[2]{\tikz[baseline=-2pt]{%
    \draw[*-*](0,0) -- (\SajadLineLength,0)node[pos=0,below]{$#1$}node[pos=1,below]{$#2$};
    \draw (0.5*\SajadLineLength,0) circle (\SajadCircleRadii);
  }}
\newcommand\SajadLineCircle[2]{\tikz[baseline=-2pt]{%
    \draw[*-*](0,0) -- (\SajadLineLength,0)node[pos=0,below]{$#1$}node[pos=1,below]{$#2$};
    \draw (0.5*\SajadLineLength,\SajadCircleRadii) circle (\SajadCircleRadii);
  }}
\newcommand\SajadLineDoubleCircle[2]{\tikz[baseline=-2pt]{%
    \draw[*-*](0,0) -- (\SajadLineLength,0)node[pos=0,below]{$#1$}node[pos=1,below]{$#2$};
    \draw (0.5*\SajadLineLength,\SajadCircleRadii) circle (\SajadCircleRadii);
    \draw (0.5*\SajadLineLength,3*\SajadCircleRadii) circle (\SajadCircleRadii);
  }}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{displaymath}
  A=
  \SajadLine{x_1}{x_2} 
  +\SajadLineCircle{x_1}{x_2}
  +\SajadLineCircleMid{x_1}{x_2}
  +\SajadLineDoubleCircle{x_1}{x_2}
\end{displaymath}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but I am not able to cut off the written statements from my pdf..please comment on that

Comment: @Sajad Shiekh: I have corrected a typo in the Mid variant. But I don't really understand what you want to cut off from what, and in which pdf. If it is the labels try e.g. `\SajadLineCircle{}{}`.